# Postman json collection runing from jenkins with newman batch command. Binary getting populated in jenkins screen, Please guide me to fix this issue

Tags: json, jenkins, newman

I have developed a postman collection. exported as json and runing from jenkins with batch command as.... "newman -c CollectionName.json  -O output.json – H Reports.html". Binary getting populated in jenkins screen....

Example...
[90mâ”Œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€[39m[90mâ”¬â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€[39m[90mâ”¬â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”�[39m
[90mâ”‚[39m                         [90mâ”‚[39m executed [90mâ”‚[39m   failed [90mâ”‚[39m
[90mâ”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€[39m[90mâ”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€[39m[90mâ”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤[39m
[90mâ”‚[39m              [32miterations[39m [90mâ”‚[39m        1 [90mâ”‚[39m        0 [90mâ”‚[39m
[90mâ”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€[39m[90mâ”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€[39m[90mâ”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤[39m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the option --disable-unicode in your newman command? 
So, your newman command should look like the following:

```
newman run --disable-unicode "CollectionName.json"....<other arguments as required>
```

([Here's](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#newman-run-collection-file-source-options) a link that can be used as a guide for newman commands).

By the way, in general, on Jenkins, if you want to totally solve this issue regarding special characters, you may take at look at [this](https://medium.com/pacroy/how-to-fix-jenkins-console-log-encoding-issue-on-windows-a1f4b26e0db4).

Answer (score 1):

This might help someone:
We had jenkins 2.204 locally running on a windows 10 machine and had the same issue. We had to supply `--disable-unicode` at the end and also had to use keyword node at the beginning of the command like:

`cd C:\\Users\\<userId>\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\newman\\bin
node newman run "C:\\Users\\<userId>\\develop\\postman\\Sample-Postman-automated-tests.postman_collection.json" --disable-unicode`

Found help on this link: https://www.toolsqa.com/postman/run-postman-collection-on-jenkins/

Comment: You need not add 'node' in the prefix of the newman command if you have added Node  in the Environment Variables. It's always a good practice to keep Node to the Environment variable